# Convergence of power series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{(\beta n)^n}{n!}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here are some problems I've faced:

Investigate the convergence of : $$\sum_1^\infty \frac{(\beta n)^n}{n!}$$

So setting  $$a_n= \frac{n^n}{n!}$$ And applying the formula that $$\frac{1}{R}= \lim|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$ Hoping to find a radius of convergence, here are the steps.:

$$\lim|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\frac{(n+1)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1)n^n}|=|(n+\frac{1}{n})^n|=|e|$$

So $-e<\beta<e$ is interval of convergence. Answer sheet says $-e^{-1}<b<e^{-1}$ , what have I done wrong?

Comment: Where did $\beta$ go? Use the ratio test with $a_n=\frac{(\beta n)^n}{n!}$ and see what values of $\beta$ give you a ratio $<1$.

Comment: You show that $\frac{1}{R}=e$, so that $R=\frac{1}{e}$--not $e$ as you write in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the $\beta$, which gives you

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\beta\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)n^n}\right|=|\beta|e<1$$

Thus,

$$|\beta|<e^{-1}$$

or

$$-e^{-1}<\beta<e^{-1}$$

Comment: what about when $|\beta|= e^{-1}$? I assume we have to use some limit comparison test

Comment: Well, it clearly converges for $\beta=-1$ by the alternating test, and at $\beta=1$, we can use Stirling's approximation and limit comparison to deduce divergence.

Comment: wait so it converges outside of the negative bounds? Are you talking about absolute convergence?

Comment: No, it doesn't converge for $\beta<-1$ by the ratio test.

Comment: ? not sure what you're saying. -1 is outside the bound you gave

Comment: @gebra When you use the ratio test, you get open intervals of convergence, since the ratio test can't tell you anything if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=1$$thus, we must test each boundary separately as I did in the comments.

Comment: ok, i think you miswrote or something, $\beta = e^{-1}$ you mean, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  Where did you see that typo?

Comment: I see it everywhere. I don't know if it's just me though. Somebody else could help

Comment: I think it's just you, it appears as $e^{-1}$ everywhere for me.

Comment: That's a statistical fallacy though :)